# Renaming a specific row index without affecting duplicates (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I want to change the index of a specific row in a dataframe when another row with the same index also exists elsewhere.
The `df.rename(index={'old_value':'new_value'})` is not helpful since it replaces both instances.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42) # Setting seed for reproducibility
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(6,3)) # Creating the dataframe
df.index = ['Adam','Bob','Charlie','David','Adam','Finny'] # Setting a custom index containing a duplicate for "Adam"

print(df)
```

```
Original dataframe:

                0         1         2

Adam     0.374540  0.950714  0.731994
Bob      0.598658  0.156019  0.155995
Charlie  0.058084  0.866176  0.601115
David    0.708073  0.020584  0.969910
Adam     0.832443  0.212339  0.181825
Finny    0.183405  0.304242  0.524756
```

I need to change the 2nd instance of 'Adam' with 'Elise'.

I have tried using the normal approach with `df.rename(index={'Adam': 'Elise'})`.
However, this replaces both instances of 'Adam' with 'Elise' which is not what we want.

A crude solution I figured was the following:

```
df = df.reset_index() # Reset the index which essentially converts it to a column
df.at[4,'index'] = 'Elise' # Use the .at indexer to manually set the value of 'Adam' to 'Elise'
df = df.set_index('index') # Set the 'index' column as the index of the dataframe
df = df.rename_axis(index=None) # Also remove the default name given to the index during the reset_index() method call (optional)

print(df)
```

```
Final dataframe:

                0         1         2

Adam     0.374540  0.950714  0.731994
Bob      0.598658  0.156019  0.155995
Charlie  0.058084  0.866176  0.601115
David    0.708073  0.020584  0.969910
Elise    0.832443  0.212339  0.181825
Finny    0.183405  0.304242  0.524756
```

Now only the 2nd instance of 'Adam' has been correctly changed to 'Elise'.
**Is there any way to accomplish this more directly without resorting to such crude manipulations? Perhaps with a pandas built-in function/method?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Index.where` and `pd.Index.duplicated`

```
out = df.set_index(df.index.where(~df.index.duplicated(), "Elise"))
```

```
                0         1         2
Adam     0.374540  0.950714  0.731994
Bob      0.598658  0.156019  0.155995
Charlie  0.058084  0.866176  0.601115
David    0.708073  0.020584  0.969910
Elise    0.832443  0.212339  0.181825
Finny    0.183405  0.304242  0.524756
```

Note that any and all duplicates will be replaced by "Elise" using this method (possibly resulting in duplicate Elises), so it is not as suitable if you want to replace different duplicates at the same time.